Rspec:Rails How to test redirection after a raised error?
In the model/product.rb
has_many :line_items  
before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item


The test:
context "Delete /products/:id/destroy" do
    
    before :each do
      new_line_item = FactoryBot.create(:line_item, product: product, cart: cart)
    end

    it "can't delete product in cart" do
      expect(cart.line_items.count).to eq 1
      expect { delete product_path(product) }
        .to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed, "Failed to destroy Product with id=1")
        .and change(Product, :count).by(0)
        .and have_http_status(302)
        .and have_flash(:alert, "Can't delete product in cart")
    end
  end

The error message returned:

You must pass an argument rather than a block to expect to use the provided matcher (raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed with "Failed to destroy Product with id=1" and change Product.count by 0 and have flash :alert and "Can't delete product in cart"), or the matcher must implement supports_block_expectations?.

Being new to rails, I do not understand what I should do.
If I remove:
.and have_http_status(302)
.and have_flash(:alert, "Can't delete product in cart")

the test passes, but I want to confirm it redirects and the flash alert is correct.
